# A negative value from the top of a stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'd like to create a stacked bar chart in RStudio that shows the control mean and the treatment effect. It is usually the case that the control mean is large, while the treatment effect is small. However, one of the three treatment effects in my example is negative. Examples that I've seen on stackoverflow seem to deal with including negative bars into stacked bar plots, but I am asking specifically about placing a negative bar on top of the bar on which it is stacked that effectively "eats" into that bar, if that makes sense. So if a control mean bar is 0.70, and the treatment effect for that variable is -0.10, then ideally that stacked bar would be one shade from 0 to 0.60 and another shade from 0.60 to 0.70. It may also be ideal if that treatment effect for that bar in particular be colored different from the other treatment effects, to emphasize that it is negative rather than positive, so if anyone has a tip about that, it would be much appreciated, but is not formally part of this request.

I am including an example below. Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

groups <- c(rep("All" , 2) , rep("Group A" , 2) , rep("Group B" , 2) )
condition <- rep(c("Control" , "Treatment") , 3)
value <- c(80,5,90,2,70,-10)
df <- data.frame(groups,condition,value)

df$condition <- ordered(df$condition)
df$condition <- ordered(df$condition, levels = c("Treatment", "Control"))

df$groups <- ordered(df$groups)
df$groups <- ordered(df$groups, levels = c("All", "Group A", "Group B"))

# Stacked
ggplot(df, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=groups)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-20,100),oob = rescale_none) +
  ylab("Percent") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red', 'blue'))
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible without a lot of hacking, as `position_stack()` says "_Stacking of positive and negative values are performed separately so that positive values stack upwards from the x-axis and negative values stack downward._"